# How to play set of images with Animator in Android when OnTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a group of images that i want to animate when touch the screen. Those images need to drop down to bottom.

I just added images below drawable folder. I want to play these images with animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image7" android:duration="50" />

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:oneshot="false"` in your animation-list

animation_loader.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image5" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image6" android:duration="50" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/image7" android:duration="50" />
    
    </animation-list>
```

set your ImageView normally is like this

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/iv_animation_imageview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
/>
```

add the following code

```
    ImageView ivLoader = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_animation_imageview);
    ivLoader.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation_loader);


    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ivLoader.getBackground();
    frameAnimation.start();
```